# In JavaScript, how can I create my own Keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard

In JavaScript, how can I create my own event that I can dispatch to another function. For example, I want to create `Enter Key press event`so I may dispatch to another function that accepts Keyboard events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)

```
function simulateKeyPress(character) {
  jQuery.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0) });
}

$(function() {
  $('body').keypress(function(e) {
    alert(e.which);
  });

  simulateKeyPress("e");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LR3bq/)**

Comment: Very nice !!! It works fine. I am wondering  if it is possible not to trigger an event but create an event and send to an function that accepts event. Hence, event would not happen at all.

Comment: @user395881 can you clarify a little more? In the example the event didn't actually happen

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at [createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createEvent) and [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html)

Comment: Right ... Now, it makes sense.. Thanks